# Why does PdfName.V validate the previous value?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, itext7

I've been working with iText 7 to create pdfs, and it works really well, but I've come across an issue with form validation. The following code generates a pdf file with a simple text input box:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceGray;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.action.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

public final class PdfValidationTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("ValidationTest.pdf"));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        PdfFormField name = PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(130, 780, 126, 26)).
                    setFieldName("name").
                    setBorderColor(new DeviceGray(0.2f)).
                    setAdditionalAction(PdfName.V, PdfAction.createJavaScript("app.alert(getField('name').value);"));
        form.addField(name);
        // close the document
        doc.close();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Now, when I open the generated pdf and enter a value into the text box and hit enter, a blank message box pops open. If I close it, then enter a different value into the text box, a message box pops open with the value that I first entered into the box. I would expect instead that the value entered into the text box would be the value displayed in the pop up message box. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer! Since this is a validation event, the current value must be retrieved with `event.value` and not the field value.

So the updated line of code from the question:

```
setAdditionalAction(PdfName.V, PdfAction.createJavaScript("app.alert(event.value);"));
```